# Bootstrap 3 tabs not loading content via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am working on bootstrap tabs and all the content is loaded into the tab using Ajax via remote url. But in my case I am not able to make it work as expected. I googled thoroughly and tried different ways but none of them succeeded.

Here is what I have tried so far.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="showTab1.do" data-target="#test_1" id="tab1" aria-controls="test_1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab-1</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="showTab2.do" data-target="#test_2" id="tab2" aria-controls="test_2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab-2</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a href="showTab3.do" data-target="#test_3" id="tab3" aria-controls="test_3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab-3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="test_1"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="test_2"></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="test_3"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
              var url = $(this).attr("href"); // the remote url for content
              var target = $(this).data("target"); // the target pane
              var tab = $(this); // this tab

              // ajax load from data-url
              $(target).load(url,function(result){      
                tab.tab('show');
              });
            });

            // initially activate the first tab..
            $('#tab1').tab('show');
        });
  </script>
```

The above code only works for First Tab i.e. Tab-1 but when I click on Tab-2 I can see Ajax call works successfully but it does not loads content there in tab and redirects to blank page. I am not getting where I am doing it wrong. Please point me if I am doing wrong.

**NOTE**: I followed http://www.codeply.com/go/xZfTnAtKUM this link for this.

Comment: It is working well for me, and all tabs are successfully make the ajax call and data returned to relative tab.

Comment: Then it must be something there on my second page which is redirecting it.